# Is there any way to find frequency of a number in a given range using segment tree?

Tags: segment-tree

Suppose, I've an array [1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5]

Now, there can be two kind of operation. One of them is "update" operation , that is increase the value in index 4[1 based indexing] by X. Other operation is "query" operation, where given a range, suppose [4, 8](both inclusive) and a value suppose 5. Now find the frequency of the value 5 in the given range [4, 8]. In this case, the answer should be 4.

How can I do this "query" step using segment tree??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two solutions but without using segment tree

**First Solution** :

- Split each query into `freq(r,x)-freq(l-1,x)`
- Iterate over the input and store the counts in an array (or map if
  the range is big)
- If there is a query on your position, add/subtract the count from the
  array This should work in O(n + q) if the elements are small enough
  for array or O(n + q log n) if you need to use map.

**Second Solution :**
  use [Mo's Algorithm](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/mos-algorithm/) for solving this problem with Time complexity `O((N + Q) * sqrt(N) * F).`

Comment: thanks.. :) Mo's algorithm should work in this case.